# Have you forgotten (borrowing/to borrow/borrowed)?

Tags: verbs, exam-questions

> Have you forgotten _________ 1000 from me last month?
>
> A. borrowing
>   B. to borrow
>   C. borrowed

The answer is **A**, but why not **C**? Can anybody kindly explain this to me?

Comment: *Have you forgotten to borrow £100 from me last month* would be an unusual thing to say, but it would mean something along the lines of *Although you were supposed to borrow £100 from me, **you didn't in fact do so**. Is that because you forgot?*

Comment: I would say "Have you forgotten *about borrowing* $1000 from me last month?"

Comment: borrowing is a noun. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you forgotten *that you borrowed $1000 from me last month*?
>
> Have you forgotten *borrowing $1000 from me last month*?
>
> Have you forgotten *to pay me back the money you borrowed from me last month*?
>
> Have you forgotten *your wallet*.
>
> Have you forgotten *who, what, when, where, why, how, whether, if*...

Those are the ways the verb **forget** can be complemented.